# Is there a way to get the latency for how long it takes for a Cadence activity worker to pick up a new task?

Tags: cadence-workflow, uber-cadence

Is there any way to get the latency for how long it takes for a worker to pick up a new task or how long it takes for an activity to be picked up by a worker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two metrics reported on client side for this:

- [Activity scheduled to start latency](https://cadenceworkflow.io/docs/operation-guide/monitor/#activity-scheduled-to-start-latency)
- [Decision scheduled to start latency](https://cadenceworkflow.io/docs/operation-guide/monitor/#decision-scheduled-to-start-latency)

The similar metrics on server is [“sync match latency” and “async match latency “.](https://cadenceworkflow.io/docs/operation-guide/monitor/#sync-match-latency)

Sync match means when the task is scheduled, a worker is actively polling.
So usually sync match latency can be used to measure how much load a task list is under